# running java application

Tags: java, lucene

I need to test the below mentioned method by calling it locally by a main method

```
public TokenFilter create(TokenStream input) {
  if (protectedWords != null){
      input = new KeywordMarkerFilter(input,protectedWords);
  }

return new KStemFilter(input);
```

}

The problem I'm facing is I need to pass a string as input, but I'm not sure how to parse it as a token stream.

Please help.

Comment: is `TokenStream` a Lucene class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get TokenString from a search text, you have to use Analyzer for that:

```
Analyzer analyzer = ...; // your analyzer
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(null, new StringReader(searchText));
```

Note that it should be the same analyzer that is used to build the index.

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Comment: It IS an answer. The code snippet shows how to get TokenStream from a String. That's what OP is asking about. Anyway I updated the answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AdamDyga, It worked ...., could you please tell me how to convert the TokenStream  back to String?